# Flutter: Run method on Widget build complete

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to be able to run functions once a Widget has finished building/loading but I am unsure how.

My current use case is to check if a user is authenticated and if not, redirect to a login view. I do not want to check before and push either the login view or the main view, it needs to happen after the main view has loaded.

Is there anything I can use to do this?

Comment: It's unlikely that you want to start the login process in `build`. Build can be called at any time multiple times.

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359706/redirect-on-app-load

Comment: In my case, I want the splash screen to stay on until I have decided whether or not the user is logged in so I can take them past the login screen. That has proven very difficult, since it's very hard to decide whether the next screen after the login screen has finished being rendered or not!...

Answer (score 417):

You could use

https://github.com/slightfoot/flutter_after_layout

which executes a function only one time after the layout is completed.
Or just look at its implementation and add it to your code :-)

Which is basically

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
  }
```

Comment: See @anmol.majhail answer: `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunciton(context));` is not longer working

Comment: Hi @Thomas, it's not working for me. still get null exception. any idea ?

Comment: @anunixercoder : it depends on your use case. At times, you should call it in other than `initState`, eg. in `build`.

Comment: you should call `setState` within `yourFunction` method to make it working

Comment: @Pars no one likes to admit they forgot about this lol, including me

Comment: Is using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` a lot of times indicate bad practise in code?

Comment: @Thomas, This solution worked for me without any problem. thanks a lot.

Comment: When I tried to use this inside Stateless widget, the callback will be executed many times. How to know whether a stateless widget is painted just once ?

Comment: But how is this a good ooption performance wise? doesnt it make the app slower?

Answer (score 157):

**UPDATE:** ***Flutter v1.8.4***

Both mentioned codes are working now:

> *Working:*

```
WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
```

> *Working*

```
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
```

Comment: Second one no longer works. ```NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'addPostFrameCallback' was called on null.
Receiver: null```

Comment: @EliaWeiss - it Depends on your use case - This is just a way to call a function on Widgets after the build. typical use will be in init()

Comment: I am trying to call a function from initState that uses values from localStorage.   I call WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _authenticateWithLocalStorage());  I get an binding error while localstorage is being initialized.

Comment: The `context` captured from the calling scope may be invalid (defunct) by the time the post-frame callback is called, which can lead to an exception (e.g. if you try to access `context.state`, when `state` has been nulled out after layout).

Answer (score 101):

Best ways of doing this,

**1. WidgetsBinding**

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      print("WidgetsBinding");
    });
```

**2. SchedulerBinding**

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  print("SchedulerBinding");
});
```

It can be called inside `initState`, both will be called only once after Build widgets done with rendering.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    print("initState");
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      print("WidgetsBinding");
    });
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      print("SchedulerBinding");
    });
  }
```

both above codes will work the same as both use the similar binding framework.

Comment: what if, if it is a `StatelessWidget`?

Comment: This makes sense only for `StatefulWidget`s, as `StatelessWidget`s can't re-render themselves.

Answer (score 68):

There are 3 possible ways:

```
1) WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunc(context));

2) Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => yourFunc(context));

3) Timer.run(() => yourFunc(context));
```

As for `context`, I needed it for use in `Scaffold.of(context)` after all my widgets were rendered.

But in my humble opinion, the best way to do it is this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //all widgets are rendered here
  await yourFunc();
  runApp( MyApp() );
}
```

Comment: In GetX framework in Flutter, the second way is preferred (within the widget declaration):

`Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => yourFunc(context));`

Comment: I can confirm @ConstantineKurbatov. Using GetX and `WidgetsBinding` did not work but produced erroneous results and odd behaviour. Using `Future.delayed()` solved my problems!

Comment: hi, @JonathanRhein, I used the first choice exactly in a project and it didn't generate any error, could you explain more about the error happened to you?

Answer (score 14):

If you are looking for ReactNative's `componentDidMount` equivalent, Flutter has it. It's not that simple but it's working just the same way. In Flutter, `Widget`s do not handle their events directly. Instead they use their `State` object to do that.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyState(this);

  Widget build(BuildContext context){...} //build layout here

  void onLoad(BuildContext context){...} //callback when layout build done
}

class MyState extends State<MyWidget>{

  MyWidget widget;

  MyState(this.widget);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.build(context);

  @override
  void initState() => widget.onLoad(context);
}
```

`State.initState` immediately will be called once upon screen has finishes rendering the layout. And will never again be called even on hot reload if you're in debug mode, until explicitly reaches time to do so.

Comment: From my example, you can use `StatefulWidget` class to handle it's `State` object just like a `StatelessWidget` but I highly not recommend it. I'm not yet found any issue but please try to implement everything inside `State` object first

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data Google recommends to call data fetching on initState(). Therefore there is no issue with this solution, in fact this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: In React Native data fetching can be doing in `componentWillMount` just before layout rendering. Flutter provides simpler solution. `initState` is enough for both data fetching and on layout rendered if we know how to doing it properly

Comment: componentWillMount will be deprecated soon. Therefore fetching will be done after the component has been mounted and constructed.

Comment: This looks like a highly unconventional way to do it!... Why would you put the build method of the state inside the widget head, rather than inside the state, as normal??...

Answer (score 14):

#### Flutter 1.2 - dart 2.2

According with the official guidelines and [sources](https://docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/widgets/TextSelectionOverlay/update.html) if you want to be certain that also **the last frame of your layout** was drawned you can write for example:

```
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void initState() {
   super.initState();
   if (SchedulerBinding.instance.schedulerPhase == SchedulerPhase.persistentCallbacks) {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
   }
}
```

Comment: For me this didn't work, because at initState() time I get schedulerPhase with _SchedulerPhase.idle_ value ... what it actually worked was to add that check within build()

Comment: try the following way: `Widget build(BuildContext context) { Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() {//some action on complete}); return Scaffold() };`

Answer (score 14):

**In flutter version 1.14.6, Dart version 28.**

Below is what worked for me, You simply just need to bundle everything you want to happen after the build method into a separate method or function.

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
print('hello girl');

WidgetsBinding.instance
    .addPostFrameCallback((_) => afterLayoutWidgetBuild());

}
```

Answer (score 8):

The PostFrameCallback fires before the screen has fully painted.  Therefore Devv's answer above was helpful with the added delay to allow the screen to paint.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
       Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => yourFunction());
    });
  }
```

Comment: The problem with adding for example 3 sec is that you don't actually know if it takes 3 sec! It may also differ on different devices!... There's gotta be a way to let the program itself tell you when it's done painting.

Answer (score 6):

if you having issue with new SDK and old answer you can try my solution.I have tested it on **v3.0.4**

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.endOfFrame.then(
  (_) {
    if (mounted) {
          // do some suff 
          // you can get width height of specific widget based on GlobalKey
       };
  },
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try SchedulerBinding,

```
 SchedulerBinding.instance
                .addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {
              isDataFetched = true;
            }));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use **`WidgetsBinding` or `SchedulerBinding`**:

- ##### Use `Future` or `Timer` (easy-peasy)

  ```dart
  Future<void> _runsAfterBuild() async {
    // This code runs after build ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future(_runsAfterBuild); // <-- Use Future or Timer
    return Container();
  }
  ```
- ##### Await a dummy Future

  ```dart
  Future<void> _runsAfterBuild() async {
    await Future((){}); // <-- Dummy await

    // This code runs after build ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _runsAfterBuild();
    return Container();
  }
  ```

Comment: what does this line mean , or how it works ?
` await Future((){}); // <-- Dummy await`

Comment: It works because, so far, asynchronous code is always scheduled to run after synchronous code, so build() (sync method) will run in its entirety before _runsAfterBuild() (async method) even starts running.

Answer (score 2):

For GetX using `SchedulerBinding` instead of `WidgetsBinding` did the job

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

my english is poor
forgive me

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;
  final Duration delay;

  const TestBox({
    Key? key,
    this.color = Colors.red,
    this.delay = const Duration(seconds: 5),
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestBoxState createState() => _TestBoxState();
}

class _TestBoxState extends State<TestBox> {
  String? label;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initialMembers();
    super.initState();
  }

  void initialMembers() async {
    label = await fetchLabel();

    if (mounted) setState(() {});

    /// don't worry
    /// if `(!mounted)`, means wen `build` calld
    /// the label already has the newest value
  }

  Future<String> fetchLabel() async {
    await Future.delayed(widget.delay);
    print('fetchLabel call');
    return 'from fetchLabel()';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      width: 220,
      height: 120,
      color: label == null ? Colors.white : widget.color,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(label ?? 'fetching...'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    TestBox(
      delay: Duration(seconds: 1),
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    TestBox(
      delay: Duration(seconds: 3),
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
    TestBox(
      delay: Duration(seconds: 5),
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have a Stateful widget where I use html_editor_enhanced plugin widget. This is the only way to set initial message in it.

```
class _SendChatMessageState extends State<SendChatMessage> {
  final _htmlController = HtmlEditorController();

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
          Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
            _htmlController.setText(widget.chatMessage.message ?? '');
          });
      }
```

I tried addPostFrameCallback but it didn't work because a JavaScript generates exception "HTML editor is still loading, please wait before evaluating this JS ..."

Answer (score -2):

another solution that worked pretty well for me is wrapping the function you want to call by `Future.delayed()` as showen below:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
       Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => yourFunction());
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why would you add a delay after the widget has been built?

Comment: The delay is completely useless here, beside even if you haven't used `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`, 3 seconds is too much.