# FLUTTER: How to show dialog before beginning of the app?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to show a confirmation alert dialog right before opening the app, can someone please tell me how can I achieve that in flutter?

The showDialog() method needs a context, hence I should put it somewhere with buildContext, I assume in app's build method, but how can I trigger the dialog before the actual layout will be built on screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code below works, I guess this is the answer

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => showAlert(context));
    return new WhateverLayoutYouWantToBeDisplayed();
  }

  void showAlert(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      child: new WhateverCustomDialogYouHave(),
        context: context);   
  }
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to invoke `showDialog` from `build` method because `build` can be called multiple times throughout screen lifetime.

Answer (score 9):

In your `initState` you can add your callback which will show your dialog with `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` which will be displayed immediately after layout. You can update your layout state according to your dialog result.

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance
            .addPostFrameCallback((_) => showDialog(...));
      }


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('HomePage'),
          ),
          body: Container(),
        );
      }
```

Comment: WidgetsBinding.instance
            .addPostFrameCallback((_)  doesn't work anymore.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54553143/10269042

Comment: Yup, I also tried, not working, tried another approach, will post in answers in case anyone else needs that..

Comment: Upss. It works on my version=) Which version are you on?

Comment: On latest stable flutter version.

Answer (score 3):

Best ways of doing this,

**1. WidgetsBinding**

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
 showDialog();
});
```

**2. SchedulerBinding**

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
   showDialog();
 });
```

`WidgetsBinding` & `SchedulerBinding` will be called only once as we called it in `initState(),` but remember it will be called when the build method finished its rendering.

```
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  print("initState");
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    print("WidgetsBinding");
  });
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    print("SchedulerBinding");
  });
}
```