# flutter display message on mount

Tags: flutter

Beginner question:

I'm trying to display a message as soon as the page display, I can do it with a simple custom message, but I couldn't find any standard way to do it, all search I did leads me to `Snackbar` or `Flushbar`, the problem with this 2 is that u can only show it after the build is called, e.g. on `onPress`, which leads me to the actual question:

How do I get a call back for onMount event, e.g. something like `jQuery` `ready` method, that is triggered once the page is mounted (i.e. ready), so that I can call  `Snackbar` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate to [Flutter: Run method on Widget build complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466556/flutter-run-method-on-widget-build-complete)

answer:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


    if (SchedulerBinding.instance.schedulerPhase ==
        SchedulerPhase.persistentCallbacks) {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        showInFlushbar("Some text");
      });
    }
    ;
  }
```