# Flutter: Is there a way to check whether widget is built

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The problem is, I need to call method after widget is built, otherwise I'm getting an error.
So I want to know is there a way to check whether widget is built, maybe a listener?

Comment: As @Ampersanda stated this could be a duplicate, anyhow what you should do is make that widget `stateful` and override the `initState` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Run method on Widget build complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466556/flutter-run-method-on-widget-build-complete)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All widgets have a bool `this.mounted` property. It turns true when the buildContext is assigned.

Tip: Its a good practice to set the state of any widget only after the widget is built and I usually use this bool to set states once it is true. It is an error to call setState when a widget is unmounted or before it is mounted.

In your case, I feel you need the same thing, run your method if `this.mounted == true`.