# Flutter (web) video_player Autoplay

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

does anyone know what I need to do in order to get my videos to play automatically once my flutter website has loaded?

The only thing I've managed so far is to get them to play/loop if I refresh the page manually.

I'm sure it's something simple but after 3 months of not coding at all I'm a little rusty...

At the moment I'm calling `_videoPlayerController.play()` inside the `FutureBuilder`

```
class VideoWithChild extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoSource;
  final FractionalOffset alignment;
  final TextAlign textAlign;
  final Widget child;

  const VideoWithChild(
      {Key key, this.videoSource, this.alignment, this.textAlign, this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoWithChildState createState() =>
      _VideoWithChildState(videoSource, alignment, textAlign, child);
}

class _VideoWithChildState extends State<VideoWithChild> {
  final String videoSource;
  final TextAlign textAlign;
  final Widget child;
  final FractionalOffset alignment;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  VoidCallback listener;

  _VideoWithChildState(
      this.videoSource, this.alignment, this.textAlign, this.child);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.asset(videoSource);
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _videoPlayerController.initialize();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            _videoPlayerController.dataSource.isNotEmpty) {
              print('connection state');
          _videoPlayerController.play();
          _videoPlayerController.setLooping(true);
          return AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
                LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (context, constraints) {
                    return Align(alignment: alignment, child: child);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                Color(0xff49148c),
              ),
            )),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('dispose');
    super.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chrome or other browsers might not allow auto play video as pointed out [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) and mentioned by the `video_player_web` author [here](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web#autoplay).

However you can autoplay it if you mute the volume. Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466556/flutter-run-method-on-widget-build-complete)'s answer, you can use the `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` to autoplay your video.  In your `initState` method try to add the following lines.

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // mutes the video
      _videoPlayerController.setVolume(0); 
      // Plays the video once the widget is build and loaded.
      _videoPlayerController.play();
    });
```

However if you want the video to be played once the entire website is loaded, you may want to do it in javascript using `body` tags `onload` property as defined [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp).

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the reply - your solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

Even simpler: Put it in the 'then' part after initializing the controller

```
_controller.initialize().then((value) => _controller.play())
```