# Flutter [animations] OpenContainer how to detect the animation is finished

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm using `OpenContainer animation` to open a screen that could display alert dialog upon the opening of the screen - the case of the item the screen is trying to display is no longer valid or deleted.

Because OpenContainer renders the screen during the animation, the alert dialog is displayed several times.

**My attempt** to address the issue was to modify the `OpenContainer buildPage` method to return animation status to `openBuilder` callback. Is there better way to do without modifying `OpenContainer` code?

```dart
child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animation,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          if (animation.isCompleted) {
            return SizedBox.expand(
              child: Material(
                color: openColor,
                elevation: openElevation,
                shape: openShape,
                child: Builder(
                  key: _openBuilderKey,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return openBuilder(context, closeContainer, false); // added false
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
```

Code to reproduce the issue - https://gist.github.com/MartinJLee/0992a986ad641ef5b4f477fb1ce69249
[image: the issue]

Comment: Consider using an [AlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) instead.

Comment: @dev-aentgs I'm using AlertDialog

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say if the `OpenContainer` is only displaying the new screen for `AlertDialog` then use `AlertDialog` directly as it hides the original screen by default. Can you add the images for the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I'm not just displaying `AlertDialog` the dialog will display on the top of the original content which may be deleted by the publisher. The screenshot is what will be displayed after the animation by `OpenContainer`.

Comment: Thanks. Try the below answer.

Comment: I guess I should be using something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466556/flutter-run-method-on-widget-build-complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do using the following code on the container for openBuilder.

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
  }
```

see original answers - [Flutter: Run method on Widget build complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466556/flutter-run-method-on-widget-build-complete)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to your AnimationController something like this

Consider you have an AnimationController like this -

```
AnimationController _animationController =  AnimationController(
            vsync: this, 
            duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
      );
```

Then you can add a Status Listener to this `_animationController` using the addStatusListener method, something like this -

```
_animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
        if(status == AnimationStatus.completed){
          //Do something here
        }
    });
```

This listener will be called everytime the animation state changes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As far as I know, we cannot add `AnimationController` to `OpenContainer`

Comment: animation parameter of AnimationBuilder takes an instance of AnimationController.

Comment: Sorry I updated my question, I'm asking if there is a better way to address the issue without modifying `OpenContainer` code