# How to know when the app is loaded in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app I'm playing an animation. And I want to start the playback only after all the widgets on the page have loaded. Essencially I'm looking for the JS equivalnat of `window.onload` in flutter. Right now the animation starts as soon as it can and the result it that when the app lunches I see a white screen while the app is loading for a few seconds and when the app is finally loaded the animation is already half way through the playback.

Is there a signal or event in flutter that will let me know that the app has loaded?

Comment: Depends on where you place the start() function in the code, where is it placed currently?

Comment: @Arvind Are you refereing to the function that starts the animation?

Comment: Please check this complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61647060/2271213

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a widget you can use

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
  //stuff
})
```

If you put this in your initState the callback will be called after the first frame is rendered, if that's what you need.

Comment: Thank you! This does exactlly what I asked for!