# flutter CupertinoPicker FixedExtentScrollController change initialItem

Tags: flutter, cupertinopicker

```
 Expanded(
            flex: 10,
            child: Container(
                child: CupertinoPicker(
              itemExtent: 50,
              onSelectedItemChanged: (int i) {},
              scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(
                initialItem: isIndex,
              ),
              useMagnifier: true,
              children: appwidget,
            ))),
```

I have this code, children is every changed list widgets.
When I change 'appwidget' for list widget, Can I Set initialItem Index?

I can't call FixedExtentScrollController. I have no idea.

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

First, u need to create a `FixedExtentScrollController`, which allows u to conveniently work with item indices rather than working with a raw pixel scroll offset as required by the standard `ScrollController` (source from the [Flutter doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FixedExtentScrollController-class.html)):

```
FixedExtentScrollController? _scrollWheelController;
final String? value;
final String values = ['male','female','other'];
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollWheelController = FixedExtentScrollController(
      /// Jump to the item index of the selected value in CupertinoPicker
      initialItem: value == null ? 0 : values.indexOf(value!),
    );
  }
```

Then connect it to the `CupertinoPicker` so that u can control the scroll view programmatically:

```
CupertinoPicker.builder(scrollController: _scrollWheelController);
```

If u want to jump to the item index of the selected value as soon as the `ModalBottomSheet` pops up, the following code will help u achieve this:

```
showModalBottomSheet<String>(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) {
    /// If the build() method to render the
    /// [ListWheelScrollView] is complete, jump to the
    /// item index of the selected value in the controlled
    /// scroll view
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
      /// [ScrollController] now refers to a
      /// [ListWheelScrollView] that is already mounted on the screen
      (_) => _scrollWheelController?.jumpToItem(
        value == null ? 0 : values.indexOf(value!),
      ),
    );

    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text('Done'),
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(thickness: 1),
          Expanded(
            child: CupertinoPicker.builder(
              /// if [itemExtent] is too low, the content for each
              /// item will be squished together
              itemExtent: 32,
              scrollController: _scrollWheelController,
              onSelectedItemChanged: (index) => setState(() => values[index]),
              childCount: values.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => Center(
                child: Text(
                  valueAsString(values[index]),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

`WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback()` will ensure all the `build()` methods of all widgets to be rendered in the current frame is complete. If `_scrollWheelController` refers to a `ListWheelScrollView` that is not yet fully built, the `jumpToItem()` won't work.

Read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64186549/8138591) for more info on how to run method on Widget build complete