# Schedular binding with null safety Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to start a function when all the widgets on my page are built, looking around on the internet I found this function [Flutter: Run method on Widget build complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466556/flutter-run-method-on-widget-build-complete) :

```
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   if (SchedulerBinding.instance.schedulerPhase == SchedulerPhase.persistentCallbacks) {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
   }
```

But I got this error :

```
The property 'schedulerPhase' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
```

And :

```
The method 'addPostFrameCallback' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')
```

I assume these are some checks included in `null safety` , any ideas?

Comment: add `?` so write like this `SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));`

Comment: Thanks mate, love you.