# How to call showDialog after page load without doing any action?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tell me, I have a page and I need to display `dialog` after the page has loaded, but I need it to open itself not on click, but after the page has loaded. I tried adding the `showDialog` method to `initState` but got an error. How can I display dialog after page load?

**dialog**

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => const SendEmailDialog(),
);
```

**body**

```
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  const Body({Key? key, this.isUserAuth = false}) : super(key: key);

  final bool isUserAuth;

  @override
  State<Body> createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  bool isMapList = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double paddingTop = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    return BlocBuilder<StationCubit, StationState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        final StationCubit cubit = BlocProvider.of<StationCubit>(context);
        return BlocBuilder<StationMarkerCubit, StationMarkerState>(
          builder: (context, stationMarkerState) {
            final StationMarkerCubit stationMarkerCubit =
                BlocProvider.of<StationMarkerCubit>(context);
            return Container(
              height: size.height,
              width: size.width,
              decoration: isMapList
                  ? const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                          constants.Colors.blue7xDark,
                          constants.Colors.blue6xDark,
                          constants.Colors.blueXxxxxDark,
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  : const BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(
                            'assets/images/background/main_background.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
              child:
                  _child(context, size, cubit, stationMarkerCubit, paddingTop),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _child(BuildContext context, Size size, StationCubit cubit,
          StationMarkerCubit stationMarkerCubit, double paddingTop) =>
      Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          isMapList
              ? const SizedBox()
              : GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    cubit.selectStation(null);
                  },
                  child: MapWidget(
                    stationCubit: cubit,
                    stationMarkerCubit: stationMarkerCubit,
                    isUserAuth: widget.isUserAuth,
                  ),
                ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: paddingTop + 24,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 45,
                  child: SearchWidget(
                    isMapList: isMapList,
                    isMapListChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                      isMapList = value;
                      _onDismissedStationCard(stationMarkerCubit, cubit);
                    }),
                    isUserAuth: widget.isUserAuth,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 24,
                ),
                isMapList ? const MapListWidget() : const SizedBox(),
                isMapList
                    ? const SizedBox(height: 0)
                    : const SizedBox(height: 100)
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `addPostFrameCallback` on initState.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(),
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Tie to the runner :)

Comment: Yes, I've post after testing and on flutter 3  `instance` is not nullable.

Comment: Me too. What that means is that we both answered at the _same_ time.

Comment: And now how to determine who is faster and whose answer to accept :)

Comment: @Max I'm okay with it. Go ahead and accept his answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback()`:

```dart
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Hello'),
                content: Text('Hello World'),
              ));
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

- See: [Flutter: Run method on Widget build complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466556/flutter-run-method-on-widget-build-complete)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Can I also specify additional time so that it appears after 2-3 seconds?

Comment: @Max Try using `Future.delayed()`

Comment: Do I need to specify this in addPostFrameCallback ?

Comment: @Max Actually, I think if you use `Future.delayed` you might not even need `addpostframback` you can try