# How to wait seState to be finished and widgets to be built before calling another function?

Tags: flutter, tabs, future, setstate

Hi StackOverFlow community,
that's my first question here and I'm glad to be part of this community as it already helped me in plenty of things. I looked on this topic and didn't manage to find anything.
I would like to redirect the DefaultTabController to the new tab created after waiting that it's loaded and built.
I managed to find a workaround with the awaiting a Future.delayed wrapping setState but I don't think it's the best solution out there.
When not using this FutureDelayed I get an error due to the fact that the button function is trying to redirect to a tab not yet crated as the DefaultTabController has not been yet rebuilt.

Function for adding a new tab inside a bottomSheet

```
Future<int> _addNewTab() async {
      await showModalBottomSheet(
...
...

IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                final isValid =
                                    _formKey.currentState!.validate();
                                if (!isValid) {
                                  return;
                                }
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                  setState(() {
                                    _tabs
                                        .add(_newTab.text);
                                  });
                                }
return _tabs.lenght-1;
```

Widget inside which I call the function

```
return DefaultTabController(
...
...

floatingActionButton: Padding(
                      //button to add a new tab
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25.0),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.add_circle,
                          size: 55,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          var page = await _addNewTab();
                          //awaiting this future delayed because we can't show a page which is not built yet
                          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10),
                              () {
                            setState(() {});
                          });
                          //moving to the new tab built after awaiting it
                          if (mounted) { //checking that context is still alive and usable
                            DefaultTabController.of(context)!.animateTo(page);
                          }
                        },
```

Thanks a lot for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you have right, using the Future to wait for the 10 milliseconds fixes it but it's not the best solution.

instead :
first import the `scheduler` package, it's built-in in flutter, add this on top of your file :

```
import 'flutter/scheduler.dart';
```

then, replace this:

```
     await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10),
            () {
              setState(() {});
            });
```

with this:

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
  (_){
   setState(() {});
 })
```

this will schedule the `SetState(() {})` just one frame after it finishes executing all the code in that `onPressed` function, so the result will be an immediate `SetState(() {})` after your page is on.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I checked with this solution but it didn't work, so I tried to wrap the DefaultTabController.of(context)!.animateTo(page) with the schedulerBinding code you provided and works fine :)
Thanks again and have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Gwhyyy** I discovered about SchedulerBinding.
Here a link with a similar question already answered with different solutions hoping it helps.

[Flutter: Run method on Widget build complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466556/flutter-run-method-on-widget-build-complete)

Have a good day!