# How to navigate to a screen on its own after checking certain conditions

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is from a custom splash screen kind of page. I am trying to check if theres a newer version of my app, and if found, then make it mandatory to update it, and if not found, then push the appropriate screens based on the shared preference

```
_checkUpdate() async {
DocumentSnapshot versionDetails = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('xyz')
    .doc('abc')
    .get();
if (currentVersion != versionDetails['latestVersion']) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) => PopScope(
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: Text(
          'A newer version of the app is available. Please download to continue.',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              String googleUrl =
                  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';

              final Uri _url = Uri.parse(googleUrl);
              try {
                await launchUrl(_url);
              } catch (e) {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Error');
              }
            },
            child: Text('Download'),
          ),
        ],
        actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      ),
    ),
  );
} else {
  Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder(
      future: UserSharedPreference.getUserRole(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == '') {
          goToDisableBack(context, LoginScreen());
        } else if (snapshot.data == 'wife') {
          goToDisableBack(context, BottomPage());
        } else if (snapshot.data == 'volunteer') {
          goToDisableBack(context, VolunteerHomeScreen());
        } else if (snapshot.data == 'husband') {
          goToDisableBack(context, HusbandHomeScreen());
        }
        return progressIndicator(context);
      },
    ),
  );
}
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
  _checkUpdate();
  super.initState();
}

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold();
 }
}

....

void goToDisableBack(BuildContext context, Widget nextScreen) {
 Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => nextScreen,
  ));
 }
```

It is working correctly if there is an update, and displaying the aler box, but its not working properly if there's no update. How to fix it in such a way that if there's no update, then it automatically proceeds to the appropriate screens based on the shared preference?

PS: I'm new to flutter

Comment: Why do you have a widget tree inside the `_checkUpdate` method?

Comment: so what am I supposed to do? (PS: I'm new to flutter)

Comment: Inside that method, you should only call navigation methods. The widget tree of your target screens should be in their own widget classes.

Comment: Also you have to call `_checkUpdate` inside an `addPostFrameCallback` like demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682918/13625293)