# Flutter setstate or markneedbuild called during build

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learningplatformapp/AllClass/trainer.dart';
import 'package:learningplatformapp/Homepage/widget/RecommendedCourse.dart';
import 'package:learningplatformapp/futureapi/CourseApi.dart';
import 'package:learningplatformapp/futureapi/TrainerApi.dart';
import 'widget/dialogpage.dart';
import 'package:learningplatformapp/colors/color.dart';
import 'widget/specialforyou.dart';
import 'widget/courseviwe.dart';
import 'widget/LatestCourseAdded.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'widget/RandomCourse.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:learningplatformapp/provider/provider_data.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  Future<void> getData(BuildContext context) async {
    final provider = Provider.of<AppDataProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final userId = provider.userId;
    await Future.wait([
      getCourseView(context),
      getCourseNew(context),
      getAllCourses(context),
      getRandomCourse(context),
      getTrainer(context),
      fetchTrainers(context, userId),
    ]);
  }


  Future<bool> checkInternetConnectivity() async {
    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    return connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none;
  }

  void showNoConnectionSnackBar(BuildContext context) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content:const Text('No internet connection'),
      duration:const Duration(seconds: 3),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  Future<void> reloadPage() async {
    await getData(context);
    setState(() {});
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData(context);
    AppDataProvider appDataProvider = Provider.of<AppDataProvider>(context, listen: true);
    var courseviews = appDataProvider.courseviews;
    var courseadd = appDataProvider.courseadd;
    var allCourses = appDataProvider.allCourses;
    var randomcourse = appDataProvider.randomcourse;
    var users = appDataProvider.users;
    String? tpictureUrl = users.isNotEmpty && users[0].tpicture != null ? users[0].tpicture.toString() : null;


    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: reloadPage,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: tdbrown,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          child: const TextField(
                            cursorColor: tdBlue,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Search',
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: tdBlue),
                            ),
                            style: TextStyle(color: tdBlue),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return DialogPage(); // Custom dialog page
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 20,
                        backgroundImage: tpictureUrl != null
                            ? NetworkImage(tpictureUrl)
                            : const AssetImage('assets/user.png') as ImageProvider<Object>?,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 90,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: tdbrown,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Text.rich(
                          TextSpan(
                            text:
                                'Welcome Back ${users.isNotEmpty ? users[0].toString() : ""}\n',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: tdBlue,
                              fontSize: 25,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            children: const [
                              TextSpan(
                                text: 'Start learning now!',
                                style: TextStyle(color: tdBlue, fontSize: 20),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                courseviews.isEmpty
                    ? Container() // Display nothing if the array is empty
                    : Column(
                        children: [
                          Specialforyou(
                              text: 'Most Viewed Courses', press: () {}),
                          const SizedBox(height: 5),
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: courseviews.isEmpty
                                    ? []
                                    : List.generate(
                                        min(3, courseviews.length),
                                        (i) {
                                          if (courseviews.isNotEmpty) {
                                            return CourseView(
                                              cname: courseviews[i].name,
                                              image:
                                                  'assets/courseview/image${i + 1}.png',
                                              price: courseviews[i].price,
                                              view: courseviews[i].view,
                                              press: () {},
                                            );
                                          } else {
                                            return Container();
                                          }
                                        },
                                      ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                courseadd.isEmpty
                    ? Container() // Display nothing if the array is empty
                    : Column(
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(height: 5),
                          Specialforyou(
                              text: 'Latest Course Added', press: () {}),
                          const SizedBox(height: 5),
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                              child: Row(
                                children: List.generate(
                                  min(4, courseadd.length),
                                  (i) {
                                    if (courseadd.isNotEmpty) {
                                      return LatestCourseAdd(
                                        image:
                                            'assets/latestadd/image${i + 1}.png',
                                        price: courseadd[i].price,
                                        name: courseadd[i].name,
                                      );
                                    } else {
                                      return Container();
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                allCourses.isEmpty
                    ? Container()
                    : Column(
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Specialforyou(
                              text: 'Recommended Course', press: () {}),
                          const SizedBox(height: 5),
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: allCourses.isEmpty
                                    ? [] // Display nothing if the array is empty
                                    : List.generate(
                                        min(5, allCourses.length),
                                        (i) {
                                          if (allCourses.isNotEmpty) {
                                            return RecommendedCourse(
                                              cname: allCourses[i].name,
                                              image: 'assets/rc/i${i + 1}.png',
                                              price: allCourses[i].price,
                                              press: () {},
                                            );
                                          } else {
                                            return Container();
                                          }
                                        },
                                      ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                randomcourse.isEmpty
                    ? Container()
                    : Column(
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Specialforyou(text: 'For you', press: () {}),
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: randomcourse.isEmpty
                                    ? [] // Display nothing if the array is empty
                                    : List.generate(
                                        min(5, randomcourse.length),
                                        (i) {
                                          if (randomcourse.isNotEmpty) {
                                            return RandomCourse(
                                              cname: randomcourse[i].name,
                                              image: 'assets/rac/i${i + 1}.png',
                                              price: randomcourse[i].price,
                                              press: () {},
                                            );
                                          } else {
                                            return Container();
                                          }
                                        },
                                      ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I got this error when I run the application.

```
========
 Exception caught by foundation library ====================================================
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for AppDataProvider:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
===========================================
```

I got the previous error for a second, I try to add the getData in the initState.

Comment: Don't put `getData` in the `build` method, but instead do it like explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682918/13625293)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove getData from the build and put inside initState in the following way

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (mounted) {
        getData(context);
      }
    });
  }
```

```
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    getData(context);
    AppDataProvider appDataProvider = Provider.of<AppDataProvider>(context, listen: true);
    var courseviews = appDataProvider.courseviews;
    var courseadd = appDataProvider.courseadd;
    var allCourses = appDataProvider.allCourses;
    var randomcourse = appDataProvider.randomcourse;
    var users = appDataProvider.users;
    String? tpictureUrl = users.isNotEmpty && users[0].tpicture != null ? users[0].tpicture.toString() : null;
...
```